# How to automatically change a parameter sequence of a function in VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, automated-refactoring

In Visual Studio, is there an automated refactor option in C++, to change a parameter sequence of a (free or member) function, while all of its calls are also refactored automatically?

I.e. refactor this

```
#include <iostream>
auto MyFunction(const char* a, int b) { std::cout << a << b; };
int main()
{
    MyFunction("h", 1);
}
```

into this

```
#include <iostream>
auto MyFunction(int b, const char* a) { std::cout << a << b; };
int main()
{
    MyFunction(1, "h");
}
```

without having to reorder the parameters in the call manually.

I didn't find such option in Visual Studio (2017) itself and I don't have access to Visual Assist or Resharper C++ (to try if their *change signature* feature provide that functionality for C++).

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer to your question is "no", there is no such built-in option, I'm afraid.